# How to pandas df.assign() with variable names?

Tags: python, pandas, assign, variable-names

I want to add a new column in a dataframe with values from some other dataframe. My new column name is a variable and I cannot hardcode it.

```
new_column = "my_new_column_name" 
df = df.assign(new_column=other_df['Column1'].values)
```

The problem is that, I am getting a new column named `new_column`.
What I expect is a column named `my_new_column_name`

Can anyone please suggest a solution for this.

Comment: Why not just `df[new_column] = other_df['Column1'].values`?

Comment: @Chris assign is useful in a longer chain of multiple operations

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can make a dict and unpack:

Given `df`:

```
print(df)
   col1  col2
0     1    10
1     2    20
2     3    30

new_column = "my_new_column_name" 
df = df.assign(**{new_column: df['col1'].values})
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   col1  col2  my_new_column_name
0     1    10                   1
1     2    20                   2
2     3    30                   3
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Does this have any performance repercussions against `df[new_column] = other_df['Column1'].values1` ?